# Renting a car in Canada, non-US resident with US-issued driver's license

Tags: canada, automobiles, rental, f1-visas

I am on F1 visa in the US (Russian passport). Can I rent a car in Canada if I have a valid US-issued driver's license? Can I be listed on the car's insurance as a driver? I do not have international driver's licence. Not sure if it is relevant here, but my F1 is expired.

Comment: If your F1 is expired, isn't your US driver's license also expired? They limited mine to the duration of my F1.

Comment: You should be careful.  If you are no longer resident in the US, even though your US license may not be expired, it will not be valid.  (Insurance broker here.)  That may have insurance implications (i.e. you may not be covered if you cause an accident).  You should use the license from where you are resident, if you have one there.  If you do not, you need to get one there unless you just moved there and fall within the time period allowed for you to change.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie - I'm reading the question as the OP is still actually living in the US - "on F1 visa in the US", and so is actually resident (at least until the expiry date on her I-94).

Comment: @brhans Yes, you might be right, in which case my concern is probably invalid.  I inferred "non-US resident" in the question as indicating he no longer lives in the US.  He may have ceased being a legal resident, so it could still be the case.

Comment: @Snake Mine was issued in California and it expires together with my passport, in 2021.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie thanks for the info! I am currently a student in the US, so I cannot just go home and get a new license, it will take forever. Will international driving license help? I think I can get this one in the US.

Comment: @brhans you are right, F1 depends on the "duration of status". My I-20 is valid, so my US status is "kinda" valid too. I live in the US now, but US is not my country of permanent residency.

Comment: @AliceV Check and make sure that your US license is still valid (speak to that state's motor vehicle department/division) - if it is, you're fine.  If it isn't, and there isn't English on your Russian license, an international driver's license combined with your Russian license will suffice.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie that't the thing - I do not have a russian license. I passed mine first driving test here in the US, I have never had a car in Russia. Maybe that's why my US license expires in 2021, because I got it from "scratch". So it expires regardless of my visa\status.

Comment: @AliceV You might be okay then - just check with the state that issued it and see if it is still valid.  If they say it is, you're fine and should proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
I recently rented a car (as the only driver) in Canada (Montreal) with my US-issued license and I am not a US permanent resident (H-1b visa - expiring in a few months).
The car rental company doesn't need to see your passport or know your US resident status in order to rent a car to you - as long as you have a license which they recognize and either buy their insurance or provide your own, they're happy.

Comment: Not being a US resident isn't the same as not being a US permanent resident.

Comment: Having an unexpired license and the rental car company accepting it are totally different from the license being valid for the person, which has insurance implications.

Comment: If the OP is "on F1 visa in the US", then it looks to me as though she is in fact 'resident' in the US, because she is living in the US while studying or whatever else her F1 allows for a long as her I-94 is valid.